# Explain the Föppl–von Kármán equations

Tags: elasticity, continuum-mechanics, non-linear-systems

I am a newbe to elasticity.
Could someone please explain to me briefly how the [Föppl–von Kármán equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B6ppl%E2%80%93von_K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_equations) work?
What are we trying to solve for?
Is there some kind of intuition to the way they look?
Are the two terms being subtracted have any significance?
$$
\frac{Eh^3}{12(1 - \nu^2)} (\nabla^2)^2 \zeta - h \frac{\partial}{\partial x_\beta} \left(\sigma _{\alpha \beta}\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial x_\alpha}\right)=P
^2 \\ \frac{\partial \sigma_{\alpha\beta}}{\partial x_\beta} =0
$$
Each letter is explained on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B6ppl%E2%80%93von_K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_equations).

Comment: So far I figured out the first thing I am trying to solve for is `\zeta` which is how much the sheet rises or slopes on the y axis, due to the stress on the x axis. But that is not all since there are two equations.

Answer (score 5):

You are right, one of the variables you are solving for is $\zeta$, the vertical displacement or "how much the sheet rises on the y-axis", I would prefer to call it the "z-axis". There are other two variables which are the in-plane displacements $u_x$ and $u_y$, those are solved from the second equation (which in reality are two more equations because of the indexes $\alpha$ and $\beta$).

The second equation is just the equilibrium equation from linear elasticity with forces $f = 0$ and density $\rho = 0$, [check Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_elasticity).

Now, remember that the stresses $\sigma_{\alpha \beta}$ are related to the strains $\epsilon_{\alpha \beta}$ by a constitutive equation. In Foeppl-von karman a linear relation between stress and strain is assumed then Hooke's law is used as the constitutive equation. So we have $\sigma_{\alpha \beta} = E_{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta} \epsilon_{\gamma \delta}$ where the bad guy $E_{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta}$ is a  fourth-order rank tensor (do not get intimidated by that, given that we are working with Foeppl-von Karman remember that the stresses in the z-direction are zero, i.e. $\sigma_{zx} = \sigma_{zy} = \sigma_{zz} = 0$, so we can express the stresses as follow (remember that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are just indexes):

$
\begin{pmatrix}
  \sigma_{xx} \\ \sigma_{yy} \\ \sigma_{xy}
\end{pmatrix}
= \frac{E}{1-\nu^2}
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & \nu & 0 \\
 \nu & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1 - \nu}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 \epsilon_{xx} \\
 \epsilon_{yy} \\
 2 \epsilon_{xy}
\end{pmatrix}
$

where $E$ stands for Young's modulus and $\nu$ for Poisson ratio.

But you may be asking "OK, and what about the displacements $u_x$ and $u_y$ that you mention at the beginning?", well I am just going to explain that. The strain is related to the displacements by a kinematic equation, in general it is linear relation, however, in Foeppl-von Karman the relation is nonlinear, the equation is as follows:

$\epsilon_{\alpha \beta} = \frac{1}{2} (\frac{\partial u_\alpha}{\partial x_\beta} + \frac{\partial u_\beta}{\partial x_\alpha}) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial \zeta}{x_\alpha} \frac{\partial \zeta}{x_\beta}$

In summary, the second equation that you asked for is the equilibrium equation for linear elasticity and the in-plane displacements $u_x$ and $u_y$ are the other two unknowns for which you are solving for.

Hope that helps at least for future references and other people who may be asking something similar.